# docker apache site without port

Tags: docker, apache

My 1st real site developemnt so bear with me. I have a yml file that I use to spin up with docker-compose. This is run on a digital ocean droplet and the sitename is linked to it

```
version: "3.2"

    services:
      httpd:
        image: httpd:2.4.46-alpine
        ports:
          - 8080:80
        volumes:
          - type: bind
            source: ./main/
            target: /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/
```

the main folder structure looks like this with the index.html being a simple html page with references to the nj and oh directories which contain other html pages

[image]

I run docker compose and this yml file and sitename.com:8080 is where index.html loads to and not sitename.com

Comment: I don't see an actual question in there???

Comment: @JohnXF this is on a digital ocean server and I have a domain linked to it, I just didnt put the actual site name here

Comment: So ... what is your question? I *think* you are saying that your website is available on ``sitename.com:8080`` but you expect it to be available on ``sitename:80`` and you want to know why that might be?

Comment: no i just want it to be sitename.com

Comment: no port shown in the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access your site without specifying the port number in the URL, you should bind you host port 80 instead of the 8080. That way you won't need to specify port because 80 is the default.

In your example:

```
ports:
    - 80:80
```

Comment: on my server it says port 80 is in use already though

Comment: got it figured out thanks